# How to make my program loop back to the beginning based on user input?

Tags: c++

I am trying to create a repetition structure for when I type 'Y' at the end of the code to rerun the "insurance price check" again.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    // Declaration of variables
    char animal, status, continue_;
    int i=0;

    //Begin Loop
    cout<<"Welcome to the Animal Insurance Company! What type of animal would you like to insure today: Enter D for Dog, C for Cat, B for Bird or R for Reptile: "<<endl;
    cin>>animal;

    if(animal=='D' || animal=='d') {
    cout<<"You have selected a dog, has your dog been neutered? Enter Y for Yes or N for NO."<<endl;
    cin>>status;
    if(status=='Y' || status=='y')
    cout<<"The insurance for your dog cost is $50."<<endl;
    else if(status =='N' || status=='n')
    cout<<"The insurance for your dog cost is $80."<<endl;
    else
    cout<<"Invalid Input, please type Y or N"<<endl;
}

else if (animal=='C' || animal=='c') {
    cout<<"You have selected a cat, has your cat been neutered? Enter Y for Yes or N for NO."<<endl;
    cin>>status;
    if(status=='Y' || status=='y')
    cout<<"The insurance for your cat cost is $40."<<endl;
    else if(status =='N' || status=='n')
    cout<<"The insurance for your cat cost is $60."<<endl;
    else
    cout<<"Invalid Input, please type Y or N"<<endl;
}

else if (animal=='B' || animal=='b' || animal=='R' || animal=='r')
cout<<"The insurance cost will be $10"<<endl;
else
cout<<"Invalid Input"<<endl;

cout<<"Do you want to insure another animal? Enter Y for Yes or N for NO."<<endl;
cin>>continue_;
if(continue_=='n' || continue_=='N') 
cout<<"Thank you for using Animal Insurance Company"<<endl;


return 0;
}
```

How do I make the code loop back to the beginning?

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend you use a do while loop. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_do_while_loop.htm

```
do
{
// begin loop
...

}while(continue_!='n' && continue_!='N');
```

Answer (score 0):

Well for starters you would need a loop...

In this example, probably a while loop (pre-test if you are interested in looking it up)

To achieve what you want, you would need a boolean flag, and would run the loop as long as the flag is set to true.

(Assuming that the rest of your code works fine)

```
// Declaration of variables
char animal, status, continue_;
int i=0;
bool running = true;  



//Begin Loop
while (running == true) {

    // Rest of program

    cout<<"Do you want to insure another animal? Enter Y for Yes or N for NO."<<endl;
    cin>>continue_;
    if(continue_=='n' || continue_=='N') {
        cout<<"Thank you for using Animal Insurance Company"<<endl;
        running = false;
    }
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: I hate to be an annoyance, but I cant seem to get your method to work. What is wrong with my code now?

Comment: https://gyazo.com/9b286dff70380a8a67b1211c01a88bf7 - here is an image of my code. It works, but it doesnt loop when I type 'Y' at the end to "ensure another animal". The goto loop that another member seemed to work, but I am hesitant to use it because my professor never taught us that method.

Comment: When comparing values, you need 2 equals signs, not just one. You did this in line 14 of your code.

Comment: Also, you are missing a few things at the end of the file. You need to add the line `running = false;` into the final if statement, which means you will need a set of braces, and the return statement should be between the two braces you already have there, not before both.

Comment: Thank you SO much for the help Matt! I truly truly appreciate it, I was stuck on this assignment for about three hours not and felt horrible that I couldnt move on, but your solution seems to have helped me get over the hump.

Comment: https://gyazo.com/42c3809fa90f9cac8ced07011f324b0d  -  Heres my final code, does it look right to you? It works, but im just double checking haha

Comment: I also have one more question, how come for the first running==true statement, I had to use two equal signs where as in the last running=false statement, only one was used?

Comment: '==' is a comparison operator. It takes 2 values, and returns true if they are equal and false if they are not. '=' is the assignment operator. It changes the value stored in the left hand variable to the value of the right hand side. Your code looks alright, although indenting it consistently will make it easier to read (And make your teacher happier)

Answer (score 0):

B. Ward is right, you have to use "nested" do-while loops to fully solve your problem. Because there are other conditions inside your code that needs to be met before program can proceed and they will also require the services of the do-while loop. Like this;

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    // Declaration of variables
    char animal, status, continue_;
    int i=0;

    //Begin Loop
    do {
        cout<<"Welcome to the Animal Insurance Company! What type of animal would you like to insure today: Enter D for Dog, C for Cat, B for Bird or R for Reptile: "<<endl;
        cin >> animal;
        if(animal=='D' || animal=='d') {
            cout<<"You have selected a dog, has your dog been neutered? Enter Y for Yes or N for NO."<<endl;

            //until the required input is entered, program will keep asking for it
            do {
                cin>>status;
                if(status=='Y' || status=='y') {
                    cout<<"The insurance for your dog cost is $50."<<endl;
                    break;
                }
                else if(status =='N' || status=='n') {
                    cout<<"The insurance for your dog cost is $80."<<endl;
                    break;
                }

                else {
                    cout<<"Invalid Input, please type Y or N"<<endl;
                }

            }while(status != 'y' || status != 'Y' || status != 'n' || status != 'N');

        }

        else if (animal=='C' || animal=='c') {
            cout<<"You have selected a cat, has your cat been neutered? Enter Y for Yes or N for NO."<<endl;

            //until the required input is entered, program will keep asking for it
            do {
                cin>>status;
                if(status=='Y' || status=='y') {
                    cout<<"The insurance for your dog cost is $40."<<endl;
                    break;
                }
                else if(status =='N' || status=='n') {
                    cout<<"The insurance for your dog cost is $60."<<endl;
                    break;
                }

                else {
                    cout<<"Invalid Input, please type Y or N"<<endl;
                }

            }while(status != 'y' || status != 'Y' || status != 'n' || status != 'N');

        }

        else if (animal=='B' || animal=='b' || animal=='R' || animal=='r')
            cout<<"The insurance cost will be $10"<<endl;
        else {
            cout<<"Invalid Input"<<endl;
            break;
        }

        cout<<"Do you want to insure another animal? Enter Y for Yes or N for NO."<<endl;
        cin>>continue_;
        if(continue_=='n' || continue_=='N')
            cout<<"Thank you for using Animal Insurance Company"<<endl;

    }while(continue_ == 'y' || continue_ == 'Y');

    return 0;
}
```